# How to query LIST by passing parameter?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework 5.0 and I created my database from model. The below is the screenshot of the edmx diagram.

[image]

I am working towards to a below structure of data:

On given Client ID give me list of Theader which belongs to that ClientID and its TReports so I modeled my models as below:

```
public class TReportHeaderModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string  THeaderTitle { get; set; }
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }

    public IList<TReportModel> TReports { get; set; }
}

public class TReportModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string  TReportName { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }
}
```

So when I query to get `Theaders` and its each report for given clientID:

I am listing the headers first for given clientID:

```
public IList<TReportHeaderModel> GetHeadersByClient(int ClientID)
{
    using (var connection = new TReportEntitiesConnection())
    {
        var clientHeaders= (from st in connection.THeaders
                            where ClientID == st.ClientID
                            select new TReportHeaderModel
                            {
                                ID=st.ID,
                                THeaderTitle=st.THeaderTitle,
                                RowNumber=st.RowNumber
                            }).ToList();

        return (clientHeaders);
    }
}
```

And then to get the list of reports for each title and this is where I am stuck--->

```
public IList<TReportModel> GetChildReportsByHeader(int THeaderID)
{
    using (var connection = new TReportEntitiesConnection())
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Instead of separating it by get the headers by client first and then get the report by header id, is it possible to combine it in one method? sorry for the confusing explanation but I am new to LINQ Query so please understand.

The below is the ideal structure for the UI implemetation:

Client ID =2

Header 1

- TReportName
- URL

Header 2

- TReportName
- URL

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to combine it in one method?

If I understand you correctly, this is what you're looking for:

```
using (var connection = new TReportEntitiesConnection())
{
    var clientHeaders = (
        from st in connection.THeaders
        where ClientID == st.ClientID
        select new TReportHeaderModel
        {
            ID=st.ID,
            THeaderTitle = st.THeaderTitle,
            RowNumber = st.RowNumber,
            Reports = from r in st.TReports
                      select new TReportModel
                      {
                        ID = r.ID,
                        TReportName = r.TReportName,
                        URL = r.URL,
                        RowNumber = r.RowNumber,
                      }
        }
    ).ToList();
}
return clientHeaders;
```

Note that for this to work, `TReportHeaderModel.TReports` should be `IEnumerable<TReportModel>`.

Comment: In this case, how would I return the model?

Comment: `clientHeaders` is `List<TReportHeaderModel>` so you can return it. This produces `TReportHeaderModel` containing `TReportModel`s, so I think that is your "ideal structure".

Comment: Since I have this method, I really do not need the method ''GetChildReportsByHeader, right?

Comment: return clientHeaders.ToList(); is it correct to return this way?

Comment: Well, either the first or the second `ToList` is unnecessary, but yes.

Comment: gotcha! thank you! Can I bug you with more questions in regards of inserting data for this ? :-)

Comment: It's always better to ask subsequent questions in a new post so you can give all required background information. Of course I'll be happy to see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would suggest you separate the methods for getting your data and transforming your data into DTOs like this (And usually I have the connection defined at the class level, not at the method level because I will reuse the connection many times, and I prefer keeping my data accesses as lazy as possible):

```
TReportEntitiesConnection conn = new TReportEntitiesConnection();
```

Then I will create extension methods like so:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
  public IQueryable<THeader> ByClientId(this IQuerable<THeader> conn, int ClientID)
  {
    return conn
      .Include(h=>h.Reports)
      .Where(h=>h.ClientID==ClientID);
  }
  public TReportHeaderModel ToDto(this THeader t)
  {
    return new TReportHeaderModel
    {
      ID=t.ID,
      ClientID=t.ClientID,
      THeaderTitle=t.THeaderTitle,
      RowNumber=t.RowNumber,
      Reports=t.Reports.ToDto()
    };
  }
  public TReportModel ToDto(this TReport r)
  {
    return new TReportModel
    {
      ID=r.ID,
      TReportName=r.TReportName,
      URL=r.URL,
      RowNumber=r.RowNumber
    };
  }
  public IEnumerable<TReportHeaderModel> ToDto(this IEnumerable<THeader> h)
  {
    return h.Select(x=>x.ToDto());
  }
  public IEnumerable<TReportModel> ToDto(this IEnumerable<TReport> r)
  {
    return r.Select(x=>x.ToDto());
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
var result=conn.THeaders.ByClientId(200).ToDto();
```

If you prefer not having your connection at the module level, that is easy too:

```
using(var connection = new TReportEntitiesConnection())
{
  var result=connection.THeaders.ByClientId(200).ToDto();
}
```

(or use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) and skip all the manual Dto conversions)